# AttributeError: type object 'StringMethods' has no attribute '_make_accessor'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I know there are so man questions asking of "AttributeError"
But i couldn't solve my problem.
It seems to be a problem with os, because it works well on my friend's computer that uses mac, which causes problems on my computer using windows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import konlpy
from konlpy.tag import Twitter
import nltk
from gensim import models
import re
import requests
import pickle
with open('labeled_data.pkl', 'rb') as data:
    data_refd = pickle.load(data)
data_refd.shape
```

So far this is my code, and of course 'labeled_data.pkl' is in my home directory.

And I got the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-df61982f39de> in <module>()
      1 with open('labeled_data.pkl', 'rb') as data:
----> 2     data_refd = pickle.load(data)
      3 data_refd.shape()

C:\Users\ji\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in <module>()
    104 
    105 
--> 106 class Index(IndexOpsMixin, PandasObject):
    107     """
    108     Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set. The basic object

C:\Users\ji\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in Index()
    177 
    178     # String Methods
--> 179     str = accessor.AccessorProperty(strings.StringMethods)
    180 
    181     def __new__(cls, data=None, dtype=None, copy=False, name=None,

C:\Users\ji\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py in __init__(self, accessor_cls, construct_accessor)
     45         self.accessor_cls = accessor_cls
     46         self.construct_accessor = (construct_accessor or
---> 47                                    accessor_cls._make_accessor)
     48         self.__doc__ = accessor_cls.__doc__
     49 

AttributeError: type object 'StringMethods' has no attribute '_make_accessor'
```

I do not know what the problem is. I would appreciate your help.